# Drop columns from pandas dataframe where header contains int from a range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df_alltrades with a number of similar columns where the string includes integers:

```
    instrument  Bid0Mkt  Bid1Mkt  Bid2Mkt  Bid3Mkt Bid4Mkt  ...
0   EURUSD      1.1      1.2      1.2      1.3     1.3
1   NZDUSD      0.6      0.65     0.7      0.9     0.92
.   .           .        .        .        .       
.   .           .        .        .        .
```

I also have corresponding columns for `OfferXMkt` and a number of other columns formatted as str.

I want to remove any columns where `X` in `BidXMkt` and `OfferXMkt` is greater than 0 so that I end up with something like:

```
     instrument  Bid0Mkt  Offer0Mkt ...
0    EURUSD      1.1      
1    NZDUSD      0.6      
.    .           .        
.    .           .
```

I can do this by writing out each if statement

```
for column in df_alltrades.columns:
    if '1' in column:
        df_alltrades.drop(columns=column, inplace=True)
    if '2' in column:
        df_alltrades.drop(columns=column, inplace=True)
    if '3' in column:
        df_alltrades.drop(columns=column, inplace=True)
    if '4' in column:
        df_alltrades.drop(columns=column, inplace=True)
```

but I was hoping to clean it up with a loop, something like:

```
for column in df_alltrades.columns:
    for C in range(1, 5):
        if C in column:
            df_alltrades.drop(columns=column, inplace=True)
```

but I'm getting the error:
`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int`

I have also tried things like;

```
for X in range(1, 5):
    BidMkt = 'Bid{}Mkt'.format(X)

    df_new = df_alltrades.drop([BidMkt], axis = 1)
```

which even though `print(BidMkt)` gives the full list, only `Bid4Mkt` is dropped.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you where the problem is C needs to be a string not an integer:

```
   for column in df_alltrades.columns:
        for C in range(1, 5):
            if str(C) in column:
                df_alltrades.drop(columns=column, inplace=True)
```

but if I were you I would first do this to get the headers as a list

```
headers = list(df.columns.values)
```

Filter the necessary columns from this list  and then use it to slice the Dataframe like this

```
df = df[headers]
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! Just the `if str(C) in column:` line has fixed my problem, this was driving me mad

Answer (score 1):

Check what columns don't have 0 in it:

```python
for column in df_alltrades.columns:
    if 'Bid' in column and '0' not in column:
        df_alltrades.drop(columns=column, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would remove all other columns I have though, including instrument (and others not listed)

Comment: @cscarlet Sorry, I had forgot about restricting it only to those columns. Would the edit work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Create a remove list using list comprehension and drop those columns

```
d = {'instrument': {0: 'EURUSD', 1: 'NZDUSD'},
 'Bid0Mkt': {0: 1.1, 1: 0.6},
 'Bid1Mkt': {0: 1.2, 1: 0.65},
 'Bid2Mkt': {0: 1.2, 1: 0.7},
 'Bid3Mkt': {0: 1.3, 1: 0.9},
 'Bid4Mkt': {0: 1.3, 1: 0.92},
 'Another': {0: 1, 1: 2}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

remove = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Bid') and int(col[3]) > 0]
new_df = df.drop(columns=remove)

  instrument  Bid0Mkt  Another
0     EURUSD      1.1        1
1     NZDUSD      0.6        2
```

Comment: Getting `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 't'` quick read [through this](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10/) looks like it won't work due to the string containing letters

"Strings with letters cannot be converted to an integer unless those letters have a special meaning in Python."

Comment: @cscarlet then your actual column layout is not the same as your example. Do your `Bid` columns begin at `df.columns[1:]` Probably not. `df.columns[1:]` skips the first column, which in your example is `instrument` That way I am only looking at the bid columns.

Comment: Ah okay, they do but there are other columns following the Bid columns that do not contain integers - sorry I should have specified

Comment: @cscarlet Then just modify the list comprehension to include string.startswith: `remove = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Bid') and int(col[3]) > 0]`